# Why is usermod in EC2 userdata not applied if I log in to the machine

Tags: amazon-ec2, user-data

Everything works from a completely headless perspective, yet upon logging in to the instance --using SSM-- I'm unable to e.g. `docker image ls` without prepending `sudo`.

`$ whoami` tells me: ssm-user

`$ groups` tells me: ssm-user **But I expect docker and wheels as well here**

Userdata script:

```sh
sudo yum install -y htop
sudo usermod -a -G docker,wheel ssm-user
```

e.g. `htop` works

Answer (score 0):

I guess that ssm-user isn't yet created when user data script is run